# I'm trying to divide a playing field into equal sections

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I'm designing a sheet to represent a football field. Its currently measured at 140cm by 81cm. What would be the best way to divide this into 1662 equal sections? Rectangles and squares it doesn't matter just as long as the sections are equal. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Yes, it's possible with rectangles, 6 one way and 277 the other. You can figure out how many cm in each dimension.

Answer (score 0):

If you factor $1662=2 \times 3 \times 277$ you can read off the possibilities.  Your array can be $1 \times 1662, 2 \times 831, 3\times 554, \text{ or } 6 \times 277$